# scheduled backup mysql on shared hosting to local drive

Tags: mysql, backup

We have a mysql server on a shared hosting platform.

I want to run a backup using a windows 2003 server, what is the best application to back

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqldump and windows scheduller.

Comment: thanx thats what ive decided to do